# retrieve only a specific _index documents in the hits of elasticsearch when querying on multiple indices

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I am querying on two indices in one query of elasticsearch so I can aggregate on both of them at once. The problem is that I want only one of the indices documents to be in the hits and not both of them. Hence I would like to filter on the `_index` field in the query.

**Query**

`http://localhost:9200/products,stores/_search`

```
{
    query: {
        match_all: {}
    },
    aggs = {
        stores : { terms: { field: 'store_name' } }
    }
}
```

**Sample Output**

```
{"hits" :[{"_index": "products",
 "_type": "_doc",
 "_id": "PFS0OTD5UE",
 "_score": 123.057205,
 "_source": {}},

{"_index": "stores",
 "_type": "_doc",
 "_id": "SXBT3ER",
 "_score": 53.057205,
 "_source": {}}]}
```

I want to only retrieve the product index.

Comment: Could you update the question with your mappings, sample documents of these two indexes and the query you've tried. That'd be helpful.

Comment: Alternatively could you let me know if the field for e.g `my_field` on which you are doing this aggregation, is that field present in both the indexes?

Comment: I am talking about  `_index` field that is included in every hit result by elasticsearch. I just would like to filter on that if possible.

Comment: Could you post the query you have? That'd be helpful.

Comment: What you have posted is the `response`. If you can provide the query `request`, I can quickly check and share you what needs to be done.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want aggregation results returned from both indexes, however you only want to return the documents/hits from one of the two indexes. I don't think this is possible. You may have to manage this at your application layer. Whatever you mention in the query, the aggregation would be applied on documents falling into that query. So if you add filter on _index in query, the aggregation would also be applying to the documents from that index alone.

Comment: And if you just want to make use of a single index, just query on that single index. Let me know if my understanding is not correct and please elaborate what exactly are you looking for.

Comment: You are understanding is correct. I guess I will take care of it in the application layer. Thank you!

Comment: Also I just saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61883978/consistent-search-on-two-indexes-elasticsearch) you posted a while back. I strongly recommend to have a single index which can help better in this case. Yes its correct that lot of redundancy would be there, however that is what Elasticsearch is meant for. And if you chose to stay with two indexes then you have to manage the join logic at the application layer.

Comment: Yes my last question is related to this problem. Are you suggesting to put both the stores documents and product documents into one index. The problem with that is the stores for each single product grow in size, which will make the document size much larger and will face many updates for each document.

Comment: I thought about having the product ids in the store documents and do two queries. One on the product index, retrieve the product ids from the hits and use the to query the stores index. The problem with that is the size of the result returned, hence I would not want to retrieve a large size of hits to process on the server.

Comment: ES does not support join operations as to what you are looking for. Well they do have a parent-child concept but even then ES themselves do not recommend unless one outnumbers the other index documents count significantly. You can probably try using `nested` documents if using a single index but then again we need to rethink the best possible way of doing it depending on document size, how often you get updates on them, querying patterns etc. Let me know when you are available so we can understand more on what your intention is w.r.t querying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215892/discussion-between-fayad-and-opster-es-ninja-kamal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is definitely possible by using [`post_filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-post-filter):

```
POST products,stores/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "stores": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "store_name"
      }
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "term": {
      "_index": "products"
    }
  }
}
```

The aggregation will run on all documents from both indexes, but only the documents from `products` will be returned in the hits.